# How to determine this system of ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations, periodic-functions

I'm facing this problem:

"Suppose you have this system of ODE's:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\dot y (t)\\
\dot x (t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\
c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} y (t)\\
x(t) \end{pmatrix}$

Find the solution which have a period of 2, i.e, $x(t+2) = x(t)$ and $y(t+2) = y(t)$, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$".

This is what I'm trying: Well, if that's periodic, the eigenvalues of the system's matrix cannot have a nonzero real part, i.e, the should be pure imaginary. Let's say $\lambda = \pm bi$. As cosines and sines and linearly independent functions, this should apply:

$\cos(bt) = \cos(b(t+2)) = \cos(bt +2b)\\
\sin(bt) = \sin(b(t+2)) = \sin(bt +2b)$

So I tried to solve for $b$. But the only $b$ I find that solves it all is $b=0$, which makes no sense for me. My approach was: as it should be valid for all $t$, it's valid for $t=0$. So, evaluate it at $t=0$ and trying solving for $b$. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. $\cos$ is not an invertible function. (Hint: $\cos(x)=\cos(x+2\pi)$, and similarly for $\sin x$.)

Comment: Well, I see, but what I tried is something like this: for $t=0$, $\sin(2b) = \sin(0) = 0 \implies b=0 \text{ or } b=\pi/2$. In the other hand, $\cos(2b) = \cos(0) = 1 \implies b=0$. Where's my mistake?

Comment: $\sin (2b)=0$ means $2b=k\pi$ for *some* integer $k$. $\cos(2b)=1$ means $2b=k\cdot 2\pi$ for *some* integer $k$.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It should solve the sine part and cosine part. So, I should find an integer $k$ such that $b= k\pi = (1/2)k\pi =b$. I can't see why $0$ isn't the only option, I'm sorry.

Comment: If the eigenvalues are $\pm\beta i$ with $\beta$ real positive, then the solutions of the differential system are linear combinations of the functions $t\mapsto\cos(\beta t)$ and $t\mapsto\sin(\beta t)$, with period $2\pi/\beta$, hence one is asking that $2\pi/\beta$ divides $2$, that is, $\beta=n\pi$ for some positive integer $n$, or equivalently, that the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is $x^2+n^2\pi^2$, or equivalently, that $a+d=0$ and $ad-bc=n^2\pi^2$.

Comment: Ok, so $A= \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \pi\\
 -\pi & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ would do the job, right? It has $\pm \pi i$ as eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes. The answer is not unique.

Comment: @RaulGuarini This question is very old, but I think what you misunderstood in Christopher Carl Heckman's comment is that the $k$ in $2b = k\pi$ and the $k$ in $2b = k \cdot 2\pi$ does not have to be the same. You can thus go and look for $k, k'$ that fulfill $2k = k'$. Every choice of two integers like this will give you a solution.